# Difference between self supervised learning and unsupervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

Self supervised learning is considered a subset of unsupervised learning. Is there any major difference between the two owing to the similarity of self supervised methods towards supervised learning.

Comment: too broad question

Comment: I think the question is quite direct.